# Series and Sequence converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define the sequence $a_n$ as $a_n=1/2$ as $n $ is a multiple of $3$ or $a_n=1/n^2$ otherwise.
Determine whether $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $S_n$ converges or diverges, where $S_n$ is the sequence of partial sums corresponding to $a_n$.

For this question may I just use the test of divergence to show it?
Like series diverges, since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \ne0$ or DNE.

Comment: Did you notice that infinitely many terms of $a_n$ are equal to $1/2$ ?...

Comment: Yes invoking $a_n\not\to 0$ is just fine to conclude at divergence of the series, no more is needed. (the proof is $S_n\to \ell\implies a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\to\ell-\ell=0$ and by contraposition $a_n\not\to 0\implies S_n$ diverges).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you pick $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$, the for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, pick the index $3n>n$, the term $a_{3n}=\frac{1}{2}$, so $|a_{3n}|>\epsilon$, this says that $\lim~a_n\neq 0$.

That`s enough to say that $S_n$ diverge, by the contrapositive of the Theorem that says that if a series converge, then the sequence of terms goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by the "test of divergence" you mean this test:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

then yes, quoting this theorem and explaining why your series satisfies the conditions of this theorem is this is sufficient to show that the series diverges.

That is, assuming you're teacher is allowing you to quote such a test in your proofs...